# Forcing footer to be at bottom and Safari height inheritance

Tags: html, css

In order to force an element to the bottom of its container I need css and html like

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#content {
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

But in order to fix the height of the content div to a minimum of 100% in Safari I need to have css like this

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 700px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

This causes the footer to not stick to the bottom of the container when the content div's height expands beyond 100%.

Is there a way to have these two affects take place simultaneously?

Comment: Use `100vh` instead of `100%`, and do away with the Safari workaround completely …? (That workaround is bad anyway; absolute positioning takes the element out of flow, so you can not expect following content to show up in the proper position anyway.) Or, go flexbox - getting a footer to stick to the bottom is easy with that, and you don’t even need to have it be of a fixed height.

Comment: Have you tried `html, body { height: 100%; }` when not using your Safari fix?

Comment: @CBroe with regards to using the viewport height, that causes the page to always need to scroll to get to the footer, I managed to stop this in the browser with border-box but that doesn't work in Safari. Besides this should be doable if the container were set to a min-height other than 100% of the page. I actually don't know anything about flexbox it seems to be "new" and I'm wondering about compatibility but I'll look into it.

Comment: @hungerstar yes, I have both body and html tags set to 100% height